# Python 3 asyncio - yield from vs asyncio.async stack usage

Tags: python, python-3.x, coroutine, python-asyncio

I'm evaluating different patterns for periodic execution (actual sleep/delays ommited for brevity) using the Python 3 asyncio framework, and I have two pieces of code that behave diffrently and I can't explain why. The first version, which uses `yield from` to call itself recursively exhausts the stack in about 1000 iterations, as I expected. The second version calls the coroutine recursively, but delegates actual event loop execution to `asyncio.async` and doesn't exhaust the stack. Can you explain in detail why the stack isn't being used by the second version? What are the differences between the two ways of executing this coroutine?

First version (yield from):

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def call_self(self, i):
    print('calling self', i)
    yield from self.call_self(i + 1)
```

Second version (asyncio.async):

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def call_self(self, i):
    print('calling self', i)
    asyncio.async(self.call_self(i + 1))
```

Comment: have you tried to run it? The second version prints only couple of times (I would expect that it prints only once if it is run as `loop.run_until_complete(self.call_self(0))`)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I have indeed tried to run it and I don't run it with run_until_complete, but run_forever. Both of these try to print infinitely with run_forever, but the first one exhausts the stack, while the second one runs forever (2 million+).

Comment: then try to run both variants using `run_until_complete()`: it demonstrates the difference between waiting for the results and just scheduling coroutines.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The first example, using `yield from`, actually blocks each instance of `call_self` until its recursive call to `call_self` returns. This means the call stack keeps growing until you run out of stack space. As you mentioned, this is the obvious behavior.

The second example, using `asyncio.async`, doesn't block anywhere. So, each instance of `call_self` immediately exits after running `asyncio.async(...)`, which means the stack doesn't grow infinitely, which means you don't exhaust the stack. Instead, `asyncio.async` schedules `call_self` gets to be executed on the iteration of the event loop, by wrapping it in a `asyncio.Task`.

Here's the `__init__` for `Task`:

```
def __init__(self, coro, *, loop=None):
    assert iscoroutine(coro), repr(coro)  # Not a coroutine function!
    super().__init__(loop=loop)
    self._coro = iter(coro)  # Use the iterator just in case.
    self._fut_waiter = None
    self._must_cancel = False
    self._loop.call_soon(self._step)  # This schedules the coroutine to be run
    self.__class__._all_tasks.add(self)
```

The call to `self._loop.call_soon(self._step)` is what actually makes the coroutine execute. Because it's happening in a non-blocking way, the call stack from `call_self` never grows beyond the call to the `Task` constructor. Then the next instance of `call_self` gets kicked off by the event loop on its next iteration (which starts as soon as the previous `call_self` returns, assuming nothing else is running in the event loop), completely outside of the context of the previous `call_self` instance.

Comment: +1. It is documented that `async()` schedules the coroutine (no need to dig up the source). Important detail: `asyncio.coroutine` decorator converts the `call_self` into a generator otherwise `async(call_self())` would exhaust stack whatever `async()` does.